# How do I remove wordpress email and website from comments template?

Tags: wordpress, comments, wordpress-theming

I'm using the default wordpress comments template: `<?php comments_template(); ?>`

and now want to remove the fields **email** and **website** - I don't want them to be required or show them at all...

I realize that I could easily `display:none` them in css, but really would like to learn how to remove them totally.

Also if I `display:none` them - then the "required" email won't work properly.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using some fancy schmancy jQuery so that I wouldn't have to create my own...

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").removeAttr("checked");
$("input[type='checkbox']").css({"visibility": "hidden"}).hide(0);
$("#subscribe-blog-label").css({"visibility": "hidden"}).hide(0);
$("#subscribe-label").css({"visibility": "hidden"}).hide(0);
$("#email").val("admin@benjaminpotter.org");
$("#email").parent().children('label').children('small').css({"visibility": "hidden"}).hide(0);
$("#email").css({"visibility": "hidden"}).hide(0);
$("#url").val("");
$("#url").parent().children('label').children('small').css({"visibility": "hidden"}).hide(0);
$("#url").css({"visibility": "hidden"}).hide(0);
```

Answer (score -1):

make your own template:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_template#Alternative_Comment_Template